# ios Push Notification - unable to receive response from web service in asynchronous callback while app in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, apple-push-notifications

1) I have implemented the below method. I understood didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompleteionHandler works on iOS7+. Also, it provides only 30 seconds to complete the request operation.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
  // Invoke Asynchronous request to get additional data. 
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] // created at class init
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
      // Handling Response Data here. 
     // DISPLAY ALERT HERE. 
   }

    }
```

**QUESTION:**

1) I m  unable to see the alert or  NSLog output unless the application is in the foreground.  When i launch application, then only i could see.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the push Notification Type you have configured? Is it a Badge/Sound/Alert?

Comment: configured for all, but i am sending only badge,content-available,armyID. also, i am able to get didReceiveRemoteNotification running, and server side, there is a request also going from here. but only the response is delivered while the application comes to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle Push Notification in 2 different methods:-

```
//Receive Push Notification when the app is active in foreground or background
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
           didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

  if(userInfo){
   //TODO: Handle the userInfo here

   UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive){
        //On Foreground: May be Use AlertView
    }else{
        //On Background: May be Use LocationNotification
    }

   }

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Get the push notification when app is not open
    NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if(remoteNotif){
        [self handleRemoteNotification:application userInfo:remoteNotif];
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)handleRemoteNotification:(UIApplication*)application userInfo:(NSDictionary*)userInfo{

    if(userInfo){
       //TODO: Handle the userInfo here
    }
}
```

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification will not work while application is in the background?

Comment: It will work only if it is **active** in the background. But, it will not work if the app is terminated. So, you will have to handle the notifications in 2 different methods.

Comment: Add more info on **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method. You will have to handle the notification differently, you can not use AlertView when the app is in background.

Comment: thanks for reply. I did not understand  "if it is active in the background it works". didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler works while app is in the background.

Comment: When the app is in the background, you will have to tap on the notification in order to go to the app (You will receive notification info). When  the app is terminated (never open), ** didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method is the one that will receive the notification info. Go to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html to read about the App states.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is want i found, and it works now. Happy if it is usable for someone.

1)   APNS Notification support: While in background, you can not receive the Notification till in iOS6, But in iOS7, the option is enabled with API

```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

2)  We have to make sure in the pList file,

```
 Required background Modes -> "App downloads content in response to push Notification".
```

3)  Make sure Your payload Message contains:

```
'content-available' key with value 1.
```

4)  If you want to invoke any Network related in the callback [ie didRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler,

```
use NSURLSession rather than NSURLConnection.
```

In My Case I used

```
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
 {
     NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSLog (@" Result in String.  %@ ", strData );

 }] resume];
```

Hope it helps saving time to someone.